# Prompting when no differences when comparing files in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012, when I do a `Compare With Workspace Version` or `Compare With Latest Version` is there a way to have it prompt when there are no differences? Now it shows both versions side-by-side and I have to visual verify that there are no differences. I think Beyond Compare does this.

Comment: Winmerge (which can be integrated with TFS tools) shows a popup that states there's not difference when the compare tools open

Comment: So does Beyond Compare, which I have a license for. I do prefer the VS2012 built-in diff tool though.